# proper way to assign this onClick function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have some downstream code which is setting an object property named OnClick to a function.  The OnClick property in TypeScript is defined as Function | undefined.  I'm trying to bind to the OnClick prop in my component like this:

```
onClick={x.OnClick}
```

But the TypeScript compiler doesn't like the fact that x.OnClick may be undefined.  So I tried binding to a local empty function like this:

```
onClick={x.OnClick || this.doNothing}
```

But that returns the following:

> TS2322    (TS) Type 'Function' is not assignable to type '(event:
> MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) => void'.   Type 'Function'
> provides no match for the signature '(event:
> MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>): void'

Any idea how I can update my code to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that your function `this.doNothing` looks like this

```
const doNothing = () => {}
```

Typescript is complaining because it is expecting the function to have a parameter of type event. Pass the event attribute to the function to bypass such requirement

```
const doNothing = (event: MouseEvent) => {}
```

Typescript may complain that the function is empty though.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an anglar project then in html to call the method you can try this

```
(onClick)="x.OnClick ? x.OnClick() : this.doNothing"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try this:

(onClick) = "(!!x.OnClick()) ? x.OnClick() : {}"